# How to use Toucheffect in Maui. In xamarin forms we can do it using the xamarin toolkit.

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui, custom-renderer, maui-community-toolkit

[This is the shared touch effect files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzFxH.png)
[This is the android platforms specific code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSznh.jpg)
[This is where I register the effect and the handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vScjy.png)
[This is where I used toucheffect nativeanimation property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwwFJ.jpg)
Some properties are working , for example : the PressedOpacityBackgroundColor. Is there a way to make the native animation property to work

I tried from someone's code from where this issue was mentioned. I implemented as it is but the native animation property isn't working and also some other properties as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Toutheffect in the MAUI.

You can add the [Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.MauiCompat 2.0.2-preview1013](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.MauiCompat/) to your project. It is the .NET MAUI Compatible version of Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.

Comment: Is this nuget working for .Net 7 . I have gone through this nuget but it only supports for .Net 6 .

Comment: Yes ,this package works for .Net 6. For now , the `Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.MauiCompat` doesn't have the version for .Net 7.

Comment: yeh. Is there any other way to implement it

Comment: I am afraid there is no other package to replace it. If you want to realize the effect the package provide, you can try to use the TapGestureRecognizer.