# There is no ripple effect to FlyoutItem & MenuItem in MAUI

Tags: android, maui

I'm developing an MAUI app, The are ripple effects in Android to buttons. But the FlyoutItem & MenuItem are without it.

How to add the ripple effects?

Thanks

Comment: They are not button control on the android. So you can't add the ripple effects.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Is there any way to custom the FlyoutItem & MenuItem with the ripple effect?  Most Java apps have the effect.

Comment: You can try to refer to this case about [using touch effect in the maui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75382005/how-to-use-toucheffect-in-maui-in-xamarin-forms-we-can-do-it-using-the-xamarin).